# How can I eliminate parts of a text file in Matlab so that only parts are given as output?

Tags: matlab, txt

I have multiple very long text files that have lots of information in the style below.

```
  Target Name: Tlil@z=0070km
 Observation Time: 2022-Dec-23 at 09:35:48.500 UT
---> Lon: 4.990 deg +/- .030 deg
---> Lat: 55.5 deg +/- 0.054 deg
---> Alt: 84.962 km +/- 35.577 meters
True Solar Depression Angle:  4.1 deg
Slant Range: 590.253 km
```

with lots more information.

This is repeated over and over for different times. I am only interested in a few sets of specific data.

How would I go about taking the coordinates and angle but not slant range for outputs?
How would I take the first, fourth and last iterations but not all?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This might give you some ideas:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10059-using-textscan-to-read-in-from-a-common-format-txt-file

Comment: I think this needs distilling into a [mcve]. Show us what your expected output would be. You likely want to read line by line using `fgetl` and some sort of `regexp` to parse the text into data, but as it stands you're asking for a fairly generic answer to a specific application